# phonegap: upload picture without header information

Tags: android, file, cordova, upload, header

I am using the following code for uploading picture from android avd.

```
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="text/plain";
        var filename = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var upload_url="http://example.com";
        alert(upload_url);
        alert(filename);

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options=null;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, upload_url, picUploadSuccess, picUploadFailed,options);
```

but this code adds few extra header info into the file. like following
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1";

test
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value2";

param
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

therefore when the file stored into the server, it can not be opened as  JPEG Image.
I have found that the options object is responsible for adding those extra header info.
i tried without the options object by assigning null. but still there are few extra info into the file.

Looking forward for suggestions to upload file without any extra info within the file.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
options.mimeType="text/jpeg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you take out these lines:

```
var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
options.params = params;
```

you won't see:

```
--* Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1"; test 
--* Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value2"; param
```

anymore. However you will still see:

```
--* Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

as the web server needs to know how to handle the incoming file. I believe the problem to be on the web server end i.e. the script that receives the file.

Comment: hi simon, thanks for your response. yes you are right about the default header thing. could please give me more specific solution for web server's end. I am using WCF Rest webservice.

Comment: You shouldn't use FileTransfer.upload to send a file to a REST service. FileTransfer expects you to be doing a form submit not a REST. I've never used WCF but it seems like you need to do an AJAX post instead.